# Ubuntu installed on external SSD - won't show up in boot menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ssd, bios

So I have recently installed Ubuntu on my external SSD, and it works fine to boot it up on my laptop, but it won't show up in the boot menu on my desktop with an ASUS motherboard. Fastboot and secureboot are both disabled in the BIOS. And inside Windows the SSD is detected without issue. Anyone here know what the issue could be?

Comment: UEFI "detects" only EFI exectutables in ESPs under specific paths, like `\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi` (which is known as the "fallback" path) and a Windows-specific one. Normally distro installers don't even provide an option for you to instruct `grub-install` to do that. So either copy the executable to that path, or use `efibootmgr` to register it to your desktop's UEFI NVRAM.

Comment: @TomYan I'm actually not super familiar with linux or operating systems at this level. But how come it works for my laptop if the EFI exectuable is not already in the right path?

Comment: Because `grub-install` (issued by your distro installer) registered it to your laptops UEFI NVRAM. This isn't really a Linux-specific problem, rather it's how UEFI works. It's not that "the path was wrong", but "the path wasn't the default/fallback one that by standard all UEFI should detect, without the need of any registration".

Comment: I see, thank you. Since I hadn't started using the SSD yet I just decided to reinstall it with my desktop instead, since that is actually where I wanna use it (I used my laptop initially because I didn't want to accidentally remove my OS or something.)

Comment: At mimimum include an ESP - efi system partition FAT32 as first partition on external drive. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Then you have the capability to install or reinstall grub to external drive to allow boot on any system. Old bug and several work arounds. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 or you can just reinstall grub as another work around.